# Draw a border top to bottom and then left

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, transition

I want to draw a border from top to bottom using CSS transitions.
Like: expand border from left to right.

Example: I have an image. When I click the image a line moves from top to bottom and goes from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this effect.
You can see a demo here:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s, height 4s;
}

img:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Transition</h1>
<img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VT-PqxMMsA2wPy7kzmuKGDIzaA3AGuXKExqnfOfwTEy5AvLIMTranbfNGheRr457RD4=s180">
```